Data Cloud Activations with Marketing Cloud as the target
I'm using data cloud and I created a segemnt based upon 'Individual'
Individual contains duplicates on Individual ID because we have subscribers from Marketing cloud and contacts from Sales Cloud ingested into our data cloud org.
I created an activation for this segment to my marketing cloud activation target. It created a shared data extension as expected, and had Individual ID as its primary key. This meant any duplicates based on individual ID were rejected,
I deleted this activation and recreated it. This time the data extension created did not have a primary key set?
Does anyone know why this occurred? Is there a way to control whether the resulting Data Extension of an activation will have a primary key?
